# share huge text via `intent.ACTION_SEND` on android

Tags: android, android-intent, share

i want to share a huge text via `Intent.ACTION_SEND`; but it's just send a piece of my text... :|

this is my code

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, txt_Main.getText().toString());
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share via ..."));
```

thank you

Comment: Use the Clipboard, Luke! http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html

Comment: i want send huge text to another app;i don't think it's possible

Comment: You may create a `ContentProvider` and share huge text (and whatever you want) via `ClipboardManager`.

Comment: could you send or link or write an example ?

Comment: follow the link in my first comment